# Custom gulpfile path that is not an ancestor directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I read the [issue requesting custom gulpfile path](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/122), as well as the [documentation for liftoff](https://www.npmjs.org/package/liftoff), and [its use in gulp](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/bin/gulp.js). I can't get it to work for me. I want to call gulp using a shared gulpfile in another directory.

`node_modules` is in my `$PWD`, and the modules in it are symlinks.

```
$ tree
.
|-- node_modules
.   |-- gulp -> /.../gulp
.   .
.   .
```

I've tried a few incantations, none of which work. The most promising so far (fewest errors) has been this:

```
$ gulp --gulpfile ../../path/to/gulpfile.js --cwd . --require gulp
[01:31:42] Requiring external module gulp
[01:31:42] Local gulp not found in $PWD
[01:31:42] Try running: npm install gulp
```

What am I missing?